# Prove that a family of Lebesgue integrable functions on $[0,1]$ lies in $L^r([0,1])$ for all $1 \leq r < 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Question: Let $X$ denote the set of all Lebesgue integrable functions on $[0,1]$ so that
> $$\sup\left\{ \frac{\int_{[0,1]} |f| \chi_E \, d \lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda(E)}}\colon E \subset [0,1], \lambda(E) >0 \right\} < \infty$$ Prove that if $1 \leq r < 2$ then $X \subset L^r ([0,1])$.

My attempt: Given $f\in X$, I decompose the integral as follows
$$\int_{[0,1]} |f|^r = \int_{\{|f| < 1\}} |f|^r + \int_{\{|f| \geq 1\}} |f|^r$$
I am able to show that the first term on the left is finite. However, I am not sure how to use the above hypothesis to show the second term on the right is also finite. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function $f \in X$ and let $C < \infty$ be the value of the supremum for this $f$. Define the sets for $i \in \mathbb{N}$
$$E_i = \{x \ | \ 2^{i-1} \leq |f(x)| < 2^i\}$$
and let $E_0 = \{x \ | \ |f(x) < 1\}$
so that
\begin{align}
    \int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|^r = \int_{E_0}|f(x)|^r + \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \int_{E_i} |f(x)|^r \leq 1 + \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{E_i} (2^i)^r = 1 + \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(E_i)2^{ir}
\end{align}
where the inequality is using the bounds on $|f(x)|$ coming from the definition of $E_i$ and also that the integral over $E_0$ is at most 1.

Our next goal is to control the terms $\lambda(E_i)$. This is done using the condition that $f \in X$ and the definition of $E_i$.
\begin{align}
    C\sqrt{\lambda(E_i)} \geq \int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|\chi_{E_i} \geq \int2^{i-1}\chi_{E_i} = 2^{i-1}\lambda(E_i).
\end{align}
Manipulating this we have
\begin{align}
    C\sqrt{\lambda(E_i)} \geq 2^{i-1}\lambda(E_i) & \iff 2C \geq 2^i \sqrt{\lambda(E_i)} \\
&\iff 4C^2 \geq 2^{2i} \lambda(E_i) \\
&\iff 4C^2 \frac{2^{ir}}{2^{2i}} \geq 2^{ir}\lambda(E_i) \\
&\iff 4C^2 (2^{r-2})^i \geq 2^{ir}\lambda(E_i)
\end{align}
Now plugging this bound into the summation above gives
\begin{align}
    \int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|^r \leq 1 + \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(E_i)2^{ir} \leq 1 + \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} 4C^2(2^{r-2})^i < \infty
\end{align}
where the last term is finite because $r \in [1,2) \implies r-2 < 0 \implies 2^{r-2} < 1$ which ensures that the sum converges.

Comment: Wow! Great answer!